# Default empty option for native select on Safari shows first option as selected

Tags: css, safari, html-select

I have select with default empty option which works fine BUT:
When select is empty (first empty option is selected by default) first option has arrow as it selected on opening (checked with js that select value is really empty). Does anyone knows how to hide this checkmark on the left part of option in this case.

[image: Before opening it has empty value:]

[image: After opened with empty value:]

```
   <select class="form-select">
      <option selected value="" style="display: none"></option>
      <option>Opt1</option>
      <option>Opt2</option>
    </select>
```

As you can see it displays first option as selected but original value for that moment is empty first hidden option, How to remove this checkmark?